# How do i create a php log in that outputs hello and then name

Tags: php

When the user logs in successfully I want it to output "hello" followed by the username.

I have problems with outputting the name.
Please be gentle since I am still learning.

```
<?php 


$_user = "true";
$name = "";
$_POST = "";


if ($_user == "true") {

}else 
$name = $_POST["$name"]; {
    echo "Hello, " . "$name";
}


if ($_user !== "true") {
echo "youre not logged in";
}



?>
```

Comment: Can you also show your login form? because I think that $_POST["$name"] should be $_POST["name"]

Comment: Try $_POST['name']; without $ However there are more things wrong than that...

Comment: Please also provide the code of your form.

Comment: **1:** [booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) **2:** `$_POST` is an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) - you don't want to interpolate `$name` into they key, just `name` if that's the name of your HTML input. **3:** You've got a redundant if/else/if going on there - that could be managed in a single if/else **4:** (just to be pedantic) it's *you're* not *youre* - the apostrophe denotes the missing 'a' in *you are* ;)

Comment: This post i wrong on so many levels that I don't know where to start. Check my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you set `$_user` to `true` in your first line, later you perform the statement `if ($_user === true)` , which is true, so the code in your `else` statement (in which you try to echo the username) is not executed.

Basically this is how you process a post in php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name'])){
   echo "The name is: " .  $_POST['name'];
}
else{
   echo "No name found in post.";
}
```

Comment: Somebody wrote this in MS Word didn't they?

Comment: @CD001 nope, on my iPhone... 

Comment: Hehehe either way it's got those weird *"fancy"* quote marks ;)

Comment: @CD001 No access to my Mac here, can you please edit, you might help OP. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

// Start a server side session, indentified by cookie.
session_start();

// Handle post data from form
if( empty($_POST['name']) ) {
  // Post wasn't sent
  echo '<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>';
} else if( isset($_POST['password']) ) {
  // Normally you would handle a password or so here (either static or via querying a database)

  echo 'You logged in with name: ' . htmlspecialchars( $_POST['name'] ) . ' and password ' . htmlspecialchars( $_POST['password'] );

  // Set as logged in.
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
}

if( !empty($_SESSION['name']) ) {
  // Writing input data, htmlsp... is for escaping html (don't trust user data)
  echo 'Hi, ' . htmlspecialchars( $_SESSION['name'] ) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: `// Writing input data, htmlsp... is for sanitization (don't trust user data)` ... eeuuuuuggggghhhhh \*shudders\*

Comment: @CD001 why? Do you want a fully blown template engine for this or what?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is not *really* for sanitisation - if you don't trust the user data (which I agree is a bad idea) strip the tags completely don't just convert `<` to `&lt;` and so on... unless it's a WYSIWYG editor in a locked down CMS. There are much better tools to sanitise user data.

Comment: Don't agree with you at all. What if you have a search field which allows to write `cond1 = '' && cond2 < ''` which is parsed and fetched from a db (Jira does this)?

Comment: It would output `cond1 = '' && cond2`. So just saying htmlspecialchars is ugly is because you don't know better. One of the cleanest way if you want to display specialcharacters without breaking the webpage. And for WYSIWYG editors you often use something like "htmlpurifier" cuz the editors are often shit at generating good code. Anyway, you're taking this way out of context.

Comment: Actually it doesn't it outputs `cond1 = '' && cond2 < ''` exactly as written - there are no tags in the string, it's fine... `htmlspecialchars` is simply for outputting HTML code to the browser, nothing more (e.g. in a `<code>` tag). If you actually want to sanitise something `filter_var` is a better, more flexible choice (not my downvote btw).

Comment: Ah fuck, forgot to add the "< ''" code in my little test hahaha. Nice one. Yeah, `filter_var` does the job too, just a bit slower. Anyway, outputing a "<" in html is a bad idea.

Comment: I fail to see how strip_tags can be safe in all scenarios though. `echo '<div class="' . strip_tags( $_GET['a'] ) . '">';` `?a="`